# .htaccess setting to serve multiple domains

Tags: .htaccess

I have two websites pointing to the same folder location. They are served via different scripts. Below is the code that I inserted in my .htaccess to make that happen. Things work fine except one problem... the domains are always served by the mentioned file, even if a resource is available - I am not able to access images, css, js folders etc.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} xyz.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ xyz.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} pqr.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pqr.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines before your rules for domain names, e.g.:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =xyz.com
RewriteRule .* xyz.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =pqr.com
RewriteRule .* pqr.php [L]
```

I have also made some small changes to your rules -- they will work a little bit faster:

- No need for `QSA` flag if you are not manipulating with query string
- No need for `^(.*)$` if you are not planing to capture it and use in target URL
- `=xyz.com` searches for exact match (fast simple string comparison) while your `xyz.com` searches for this text in domain name using more expensive regex. Obviously, if you have some subdomains as well served by the same code (e.g. both `xyz.com` and `www.xyz.com`) then better keep what you have already.

Comment: thank you Lazyone! that worked perfect... the tips were very useful as well :)